# Listing all instances of any class in namespace in TCL

Tags: oop, namespaces, tcl, introspection

Let's say that I have a namespace foo.
Now, I wish to destroy all instances of all oo:object created classes within foo, w/o deleting foo (I wtill want its' "regular" namesapce variable and procs).
How can I get it done? I know how to do for a partcioular name of a class, but would like it to be for ALL classes. In languages such as SCHEME/Perl, this distinction is easy to make. In languages such as Ruby, you just nullify all non-standard classes, and that's it.Another valid option is to search.
So far, what I have found it that I need to search for all list items that exist in `info commands ::foo:`, but not in `info procs ::foo::`
However, I do not know if it "safe", or if there is a more elegant way of getting it done
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The direct way is to go through the list of commands in the namespace and check if they're objects:

```
foreach cmd [info commands ::foo::*] {
    if {[info object isa object $cmd]} {
        $cmd destroy
        # You could also use: rename $cmd ""
    }
}
```

What I'd *actually* do is make all the objects an instance of a particular class (probably via a mixin) and then nuke that class, which will automatically take out all its instances (and any subclasses of it you've made too). The class in question could just be a marker with no special behaviour.